# Github action npm module cache is not working

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I’m trying to setup an npm dependency cache in a Github actions workflow.

Here are relevant steps from the github action:

```
      - name: Clone Deploy Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        if: ${{ github.event.inputs.git_ref == '' }}
        with:
          path: ${{ env.repo_dir }}

      - …some steps removed for brevity 

      - name: Setup NodeJS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.nodejs_version }}

      - name: List the state of node modules
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Restore npm module cache
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
        id: cache-npm-restore
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}-${{ hashFiles('repo/package-lock.json') }}

      - name: List the state of node modules
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit == 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Install NodeJS modules
        run: | 
          cd $repo_dir && npm ci
 
      - name: Save npm module cache
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        uses: actions/cache/save@v3
        id: cache-npm-save
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}-${{ hashFiles('repo/package-lock.json') }}

      - name: List the state of node modules
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list
```

Note: env.repo_dir is currently set to ‘repo’. I’ve hard coded this in the cache key for now.

What I’m seeing is that a cache gets created but is not used on subsequent runs.

<s>The npm list commands always show as empty, even after the save successfully creates a cache entry.</s>

I wasn’t doing the npm list in the right directory. I’ve fixed that and now I can see cache is getting created and packages list correctly after cache save.

However the npm install is still taking a long time with cache in place.

In subsequent runs it looks like even though cache is found and restored, that modules are not available as they are not showing in npm list.

Cache restored successfully:

```
Run actions/cache/restore@v3
Received 10939974 of 10939974 (100.0%), 49.7 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~10 MB (10939974 B)
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-build-cache-node-modules-91ce2a015bd956a303adb979c31883bdc238453b3fdfa6bfdb8e37098785d2ac
```

Here is the output of npm list after successful restore:

```
Run cd $repo_dir && npm list
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.3.6, required by REDACTED@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: chance@^1.1.8, required by REDACTED@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: cheerio@^1.0.0-rc.12, required by REDACTED@0.0.1
…
```

Why doesn’t the cache work?